# How will OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient be affected by google's oauth migration?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, asp.net-4.5

I am evaluating using Microsoft's built in OAUTH wrappers, specifically looking at OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient which is included with .net 4.5.  Looking at the documentation from Google they site a series of deprecations for various oauth methods (https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable)

I am a bit embarrassed, but I can't figure out "which" method Microsoft is using to know if I am installing a piece of code that may break very quickly.

```
  OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
```

the Microsoft documentation is a bit vague - http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient);k(RegisterGoogleClient);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Thanks, Aaron